# Create an output file based from two files based on column matches

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have two files input1.vcf.gz and input2.vcf.gz and output will be output.vcf.gz

input1.vcf.gz

```
X   60060   2   572 G:1 C:0
X   60070   2   572 G:0.996503  T:0.0034965
```

input2.vcf.gz

```
X   60060   .   G   C   .   .    ;AA=0.131148;AFE=0.154639;EUN=0;AFW=0.181818;MED=0.00446429;LAT=0.0165746;VT=SNP;AF=0.04
X   60070   .   G   T   .   .    ;AA=0;AFE=0;EUN=0;AFW=0;MED=0;LAT=0;AF=0.0009;VT=SNP
```

output.vcf.gz

```
X   60060   .   G   C   .   .    ;AA=0.131148;AFE=0.154639;EUN=0;AFW=0.181818;MED=0.00446429;LAT=0.0165746;VT=SNP;AF=0.04;ASNE=0

    60070   .   G   T   .   .    ;AA=0;AFE=0;EUN=0;AFW=0;MED=0;LAT=0;AF=0.0009;VT=SNP;ASNE=0.0034965
```

Here 
ASNE=0 and ASNE=0.0034965 attached to 2nd file based on coloumn matches

All the files are .gz format

Comment: You might consider bcftools instead of awk, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think you're trying to do, using columns one and two as keys:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { split($NF,a,":"); b[$1,$2]=a[2]; next } ($1,$2) in b { print $0 ";ASNE=" b[$1,$2] }' input1.vcf input2.vcf
```

Results:

```
X   60060   .   G   C   .   .    ;AA=0.131148;AFE=0.154639;EUN=0;AFW=0.181818;MED=0.00446429;LAT=0.0165746;VT=SNP;AF=0.04;ASNE=0
X   60070   .   G   T   .   .    ;AA=0;AFE=0;EUN=0;AFW=0;MED=0;LAT=0;AF=0.0009;VT=SNP;ASNE=0.0034965
```

So for compressed files, try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { split($NF,a,":"); b[$1,$2]=a[2]; next } ($1,$2) in b { print $0 ";ASNE=" b[$1,$2] }' <(gzip -dc input1.vcf.gz) <(gzip -dc input2.vcf.gz) | gzip > output.vcf.gz
```

Please let me know how it goes. HTH.